Let $X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is the set $S=\{Y \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) : X \sim Y\}$ closed?
Here, $\sim$ denotes similarity between two matrices. Also, I am referring to the usual topology over $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ i.e. the same as $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$
For $n=1$, $S$ is either $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, which are both closed.
Also, if we guarantee $X^2=I$, $S$ is closed for any $n$:
Let $Z \in T = M_n(\mathbb{C}) \setminus S$. Either $Z^2=I$ or not.
If $Z^2-I \neq 0$, from the continuity of the function which takes a matrix $U$ to $U^2-I$, it follows that there's an open ball contained in $T$ which contains $Z$.
If $Z^2 - I = 0$, this means that $\text{tr}(X) \neq \text{tr}(Z)$. So, from the continuity of the trace function, one can see that there's an open ball contained in $T$ which contains $Z$.
Thus, $T$ is an open set and $S$ is closed.
These arguments involve a lot of spectral theory and continuity of eigenvalue-related functions in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. They make me wonder if there are theorems related to the continuity of eigenvalues that allow us to prove that $S$ is closed.
Additionally, there are many other interesting follow-up questions:
If it is not always closed, what is some example of a matrix $X$ for which it isn't closed? What more can we say about $S$? Is it connected? If it is not closed, when is it closed? Can it be open, but not closed?

"If it is not closed, when is it closed?" - I think it is never closed when the Jordan normal form of $X$ is not diagonal. In this case, you can always find an example like that of @BenGrossmann

Let $S_X = \{Y \in M_n(\mathbb C)): Y \sim X\}$.
Then the following statements hold:

$S_X$ is (path) connected.
$S_X$ is nowhere dense (in particular, it is never open). Moreover, it has zero Lebesgue measure.
$S_X$ is closed if and only if $X$ is semisimple (i.e. diagonalizable).

The first statement can be proved by noticing that $S_X = \{A^{-1}XA: A \in GL_n(\mathbb C)\}$, so it is the image of a path connected space $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ under the map $A \rightarrow A^{-1}XA$.
To prove the second, note that $S_X \subset \{Y \in M_n(\mathbb C): \det Y = \det X\}$ and the bigger set is closed, has empty interior, and zero Lebesgue measure.
Finally, we arrive at the third statement. If $X$ is not semisimple, then by using a similar sequence as in the comment by Ben Grossman it is easy to check that $S_X$ is not closed. Now, assume that $X$ is semisimple and denote by $f$ and $m$ its characteristic and minimal polynomial respectively. It is easy to see that $Y \sim X$ if and only if characteristic polynomial of $Y$ coincides with $f$ and $m(Y) = 0$. Both conditions survive under taking limits, hence, $S_X$ is closed.
